# Haskell triangle microbenchmark

Tags: haskell, ghc

Consider this simple "benchmark":

```
n :: Int
n = 1000
main = do
    print $ length [(a,b,c) | a<-[1..n],b<-[1..n],c<-[1..n],a^2+b^2==c^2]
```

and appropriate `C` version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a,b,c, N=1000;
    int cnt = 0;

    for (a=1;a<=N;a++)
        for (b=1;b<=N;b++)
            for (c=1;c<=N;c++)
                if (a*a+b*b==c*c) cnt++;
    printf("%d\n", cnt);
}
```

Compilation:

- Haskell version is compiled as: `ghc -O2 triangle.hs` (ghc 7.4.1)
- C version is compiled as: `gcc -O2 -o triangle-c triangle.c` (gcc 4.6.3)

Run times:

- Haskell: 4.308s real
- C: 1.145s real

Is it OK behavior even for such a simple and maybe well optimizable program that Haskell is almost 4 times slower? Where does Haskell waste time?

Comment: Can you try same C code with an array of 4 elements abc[4] ? where abc[0] is a abc[1] is b and abc[2] is c and last is dummy for vectorization

Comment: if you do more (micro)benchmarks I can really recommend using criterion - see http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion for more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Haskell version is wasting time allocating boxed integers and tuples.

You can verify this by for example running the haskell program with the flags `+RTS -s`. For me the outputted statistics include:

```
  80,371,600 bytes allocated in the heap
```

A straightforward encoding of the C version is faster since the compiler can use unboxed integers and skip allocating tuples:

```
n :: Int
n = 1000
main = do
  print $ f n

f :: Int -> Int
f max = go 0 1 1 1
  where go cnt a b c
          | a > max = cnt
          | b > max = go cnt (a+1) 1 1
          | c > max = go cnt a (b+1) 1
          | a^2+b^2==c^2 = go (cnt+1) a b (c+1)
          | otherwise = go cnt a b (c+1)
```

See:

```
  51,728 bytes allocated in the heap
```

The running time of this version is `1.920s` vs. `1.212s` for the C version.

Comment: Still amazed how efficient GHC is.

Comment: So we get code that is slower and more verbose than C counterpart. What point in measuring C-like haskell? It gives no answer about how usefull for a deleloper haskell may be. If you like to program like C in all languages than you should just use C. "Real Programmer can write Fortran programs in any language"

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how much your "bench" is relevant.
I agree that the list-comprehension syntax is "nice" to use, but if you want to compare the performances of the two languages, you should maybe compare them on a fairer test.
I mean, creating a list of possibly a lot of elements and then calculating it's length is nothing like incrementing a counter in a (triple loop).

So maybe haskell has some nice optimizations which detects what you are doing and never creates the list, but I wouldn't code relying on that, and you probably shouldn't either.

I don't think you would code your program like that if you needed to count rapidly, so why do it for this bench?

Comment: The thing is, that Haskell is definitely NOT creating the list because memory footprint stays very low. Then I wonder, where does it waste the time.

Comment: @Martin Have you looked at the core it generates? It's quite possible that GHC generates lazy code for your intermediate lists, in which case I'm surprised that it's runs in less than 4x the time of your C code.

Comment: @Martin It definitely builds the list of triples, but `length` consumes it as it is built, so there's never more than a handful of list-cells in memory.

Answer (score 3):

Haskell *can* be optimized quite well — but you need the proper techniques, and you need to know what you're doing.

This list comprehension syntax is elegant, yet wasteful. You should read the [appropriate chapter of RealWorldHaskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html) in order to find out more about your profiling opportunities. In this exact case, you create a lot of list spines and boxed `Int`s for no good reason at all. See here: [image: type profile for benchmark]

You should definitely do something about that. EDIT: @opqdonut just posted a good answer on how to make this faster.

Just remember next time to profile your application before comparing any benchmarks. Haskell makes it easy to write idiomatic code, but it also hides a lot of complexity.